# Java: stop a Constructor when System.in reads in a specific String

Tags: java, constructor, exit, system.in

I have some trouble with a Constructor in Java. The Problem is that I have to read-in some input from the Systme.in in the Constructor to initialize some final variable. Now i have to quit the Program when the input is "quit". For this, it's not possible to use Systme.exit() or Runtime.exit().
I have two Ideas for this Problem, but both have some Problems.

Solution 1:
One Idea would be to set a variable to true when the input is "quit" and check the variable after each Question, but that wouldn't be a nice Code.

```
public Game() {
        input = new Scanner(System.in);
        this.gameFinished = false;
        this.moveNumber = 0;
        printLogo();

        //Get Starting Information TODO Magic Numbers

        
        this.playerCount = getIntegerWithCondition(1, "Question 1?");
        //check if gameFinished = true
        getPlayerNames();
        //check if gameFinished = true
        this.startGold = getIntegerWithCondition(0, "Question 2?");
        //check if gameFinished = true
        this.winGold = getIntegerWithCondition(1, "Question 3?");
        //check if gameFinished = true
        this.shuffleSeed = getIntegerWithCondition(0, "Question 4?");
        //check if gameFinished = true
    }

private int getIntegerWithCondition(int condition, String question) {
        System.out.println(question);
        boolean inputValid = false;
        int playerValue = 0;
        while (!inputValid) {
            String playerInput = input.nextLine();
            if (playerInput.equals("quit")) {
                this.gameFinished = true;
                break;
            }
            if (playerInput.matches("-*[0-9]+")) {
                try {
                    playerValue = Integer.parseInt(playerInput);
                    if (playerValue > condition) {
                        inputValid = true;
                    } else {
                        System.out.println(String.format("Error: Your Input must be greater than %d!", condition));
                    }
                } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
                    //TODO
                }
            } else {
                System.out.println("Error: Your Input is not a Number!");
            }
        }
        return playerValue;
    }

    private void getPlayerNames() {
        for (int i = 1; i <= this.playerCount; i++) {
            System.out.println(String.format("Enter the name of player %d:", i));
            String userInput = null;
            Boolean inputValid = false;
            while (!inputValid) {
                userInput = input.nextLine();
                if (userInput.equals("quit")) {
                    this.gameFinished = true;
                    break;
                }
                if (userInput.matches("[A-Za-z]+")) {
                    inputValid = true;
                } else {
                    System.out.println("Error: Your input can only contain characters from a to z!");
                }
            }
            players.add(new Player(userInput));
        }
    }
```

Solution 2:
The other Idea I had would be to throw an exception in those two methods and catch them in the constructor. For this I would have to surround those Questions with a try and catch block, but then I have the Problem that the final variables might not be initialized and because they are final I can't initialize them before.
Does anybody have an Idea how to solve this problem with a clean code?

Comment: Three questions.  (1) Do the variables have to be final?  (2) Does this code have to be called from the constructor, rather than from outside?  (3) Have you considered doing all of this input from a different class, then calling a constructor with multiple parameters once all the data required by the constructor is available?

Comment: (1) Yes they have to be final (2) Yes I thought about that, but I have to set those variables to final, so I have to declare them in the Constructor (3) Yeah an Idea would be to create a static method which reads those questions in and afterward instantiate the Object

Comment: It doesn't have to be a static method.  You could have a class called `GameRunner` that does the initial input, then creates the `Game` object.

Comment: A constructor is certainly the wrong place to use  a `Scanner`. A constructor should be short and sweet, as uncomplicated as possible. Use another class to gather inputs. Process those inputs *before* calling the constructor.